# NSJSONSerialization not working as expected in a Playground

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization, swift-playground

I have to get football game schedule via JSON and extract date of each game of one of the specific universities.

I tried:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "SCHOOL URL")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
  (data, response, error) -> Void in

  do{
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)

    if let schedule = jsonData["schedule"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
    for game in schedule{
      if let date = game["date"] as? String{
         print("\(date)");
      } 
    }
  }

  } catch let error as NSError{
   print("something bad happened!")
  }
}

task.resume()
```

I am trying it in Xcode playground, but it does not print any at print line.
And I have appropriate url at SCHOOL URL.

Comment: after fumbling around in Swift trying to parse JSON natively, I can't recommend JSON Swifty enough. So worth it. http://bit.ly/1ODDUMx

Comment: You have not really done much to explain what behavior you are seeing (i.e. errors) and how that differs from what you expect.  You also should probably show some example JSON so that readers might be able to more readily see any mismatch between the JSON structure and how you are trying to work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use *asynchronous* operations in an Xcode Playground, you need to set `needsIndefiniteExecution` to `true`.

Add this at the top of your code:

**Swift 2**

```
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

**Swift 3**

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: THANKS! EVERYTHING RESOLVED!