# Why GCD dispatch group notify is not called in Playground and Unit tests

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have the code working in simulator/device and I'm trying to write unit tests for it. However, notify callback is not called in unit tests. Here's is a code for Playgrounds which is also not calling notify callback. I suspect it I may be using the wrong queue, but cannot figure out which one I should use.

```
import UIKit

class Loader {

    func fetch(callback: ((_ result: String)-> Void)) {

        callback("SomeString")
    }
}

class MyService {

   var list: Array<String> = Array()
   var loader: Loader = Loader()
   var dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    func loadList(callback: @escaping (()-> Void)) {

       for i in 1...3 {

           self.dispatchGroup.enter()

           self.loader.fetch(callback: { [weak self] (string) in

               self?.list.append(string)
               self?.dispatchGroup.leave()
           })
       }

       dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {

           callback()
       }
   }
}

var service = MyService()
service.loadList {

    print("Done is not called")
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @paulvs, we need to enable indefinite execution. However, how to enable that for unit tests?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class Loader {

    func fetch(callback: ((_ result: String)-> Void)) {

        callback("SomeString")
    }
}

class MyService {

    var list: Array<String> = Array()
    var loader: Loader = Loader()
    var dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    func loadList(callback: @escaping (()-> Void)) {

        for i in 1...3 {

            self.dispatchGroup.enter()

            self.loader.fetch(callback: { [weak self] (string) in

                self?.list.append(string)
                self?.dispatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {

            callback()
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var service = MyService()
service.loadList {

    print("Done is called now!")
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029442/nsjsonserialization-not-working-as-expected-in-a-playground.

Comment: Have you tried enabling (infinite execution `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecu‌​tion = true` in the Playground?

Comment: @paulvs Thanks, it worked for Playgrounds. Do you know how to enable for unit tests?

Comment: `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` should do the trick @Centurion.

Comment: Doesn't `dispatchGroup.notifify()` have to be called **before** your dispatch group is all done?

Comment: Btw, because `callback` has type `() -> Void`, as does the closure passed to notify, you don't need to wastefully wrap it in another closure. You can just do: `dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: callback)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the idea to @paulvs, and to this [post](https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2015/10/testing-asynchronous-code-in-swift/), here's the code needed for unit tests:

```
let service = MyService()

let expect = expectation(description: "longRunningFunction")

service.loadList {

    expect.fulfill()
}

self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 0.5) { error in

    XCTAssert(service.isLoaded, "Not loaded")
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have and the `group.notify` doesn't ever get called in the unit test; but it still gets called when I run.